# Is there a way to declare thread local static variables in C in Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: c

I have learned that Microsoft has no intention to support C99, not to talk of C11 and consequently does not support declaration of thread local variables in C using the standard "Thread_local". Does it mean there is no way of declaring thread local static variables in C when compiling with Microsoft Visual Studio ?